# Unable to connect 4 displays at once

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, external-display, usb-c

I have a Dell XPS 15 9500. I have a powered USB-C hub with 2 HDMI adapters. I have been using 2 external displays and the built-in display for weeks.  I attempted to hook up a USB-C monitor that I bought (using another USB-C port). Windows detects it, but it shows disabled. If I select "Extend to this display" Windows randomly disables one of the other displays (including the built-in).  If I set it to "extend" then it disables the new USB-C monitor. Repeat the process, one of the external displays gets disabled. Loop.

How can I get all 4 displays working at once?

Comment: You can't. Very, very few laptops can support 5 displays. https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/Dell-XPS-15-9500-Triple-Monitor-Setup/td-p/7703337

Comment: It's likely NOT possible with your hardware.  However, to make an educated determination if it is possible,  you would have to provide us more information about the cable.  USB Type-C cables are not all created equal in my experience.

Comment: Easy -- with an HDMI splitter, e.g., https://www.amazon.com/hdmi-splitter/s?k=hdmi+splitter . Of course, two or more monitors will show the same display.

Comment: It's 4 displays total, including the built-in. Disappointing since it worked on my MSI Stealth.

Comment: "The newer XPS 15 9510 uses CPUs that incorporate the newer Intel Xe GPU, which can support four displays." SO close!

Comment: @Ramhound it is not an issue with the cable. I can use the USB-C external display just fine if I disable *any* of the other displays.

Comment: @THEJOATMON - Except you said you had a XPS 15 9500

Comment: Right. Which is SO close to a 9510 which does what I want.

Comment: I have confirmed this works with a 9510 :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Dell Community Rockstar "jphughan" in [this post](https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/Dell-XPS-15-9500-Triple-Monitor-Setup/td-p/7703337), this model can only support 3 active displays.

> The XPS 15 9500 only supports three total active displays, regardless of how they're connected.  If you want three external displays, you will need to set the internal display to "Disconnect this display" before you can enable the third external display.  This limitation is because the Intel GPU built into the XPS 15 9500's CPU only supports three displays, and on that system, the Intel GPU has control of the display outputs, not the NVIDIA GPU.  The newer XPS 15 9510 uses CPUs that incorporate the newer Intel Xe GPU, which can support four displays.

I have confirmed using the same monitor and USB-C cable that 4 displays are supported by an XPS 9510 but not the 9500.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be expensive and hit and miss.

First this may or may not be compatible with your laptop.

Buy an external GPU for your laptop with 4 ports.
Some you can buy an empty kit and others include a video card.

Either way you will need to buy a video card.

This is an empty case and still needs a GPU/video card.

https://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/visiontek-thunderbolt-3-mini-egfx-external-gpu-enclosure-901252/apd/aa520212/parts-upgrades?gacd=9694607-1002-5761040-0-0&dgc=st&ds_rl=1285903&gclid=Cj0KCQiAr5iQBhCsARIsAPcwROMvTnMymMQn3nMkP0IockVy9DIsYhCvgYz3ZhPgZCKvTbOlfS_ZClQaAkDREALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds&nclid=9B62CgVQD8MFblhReWASG-vwEmXRB-LVaEu1o5ispC5Qoxzlyp3Rni3CfFjopfqJ#tabs_section

[2 More external GPU](https://www.windowscentral.com/best-egpu-dell-xps-15)